# Algorithm to find out if the given a number "n" , would it become "1" throughout a series of actions?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was struggling with this problem , and I can't quite figure out how to start.

If I'm given a number n , I could do two types of operations on it:

1- If it's odd , n = 3n + 3

2- If it's even , n = n/2

How can I find out if through a series of these actions , I will or will not be able to get n=1 ?

The only thing I was able to figure out was that for n to become 1 , it first needs to become a power of two.Couldn't really make any progress afterwards though.

Comment: Unless $n$ is a power of two, applying this operation will give an odd number greater than $1$, and then you will get a number divisible by $3$. Is it possible that a number will become _not_ divisible by $3$?

Comment: @Wojowu Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @MattSamuel Well it definitely sounds more of a question to me!

Comment: In that case, Furious, you have to think about Wojowu's comment a little bit more.

Comment: Take a look at what happens for something like starting at $3$.  We have it follows the sequence $3\to 12\to 6\to 3\to 12\to 6\to 3\to\dots$  How about starting at $5$.  We have $5\to 18\to 9\to 30\to 15\to 48\to 24\to 12\to 6\to 3\to 12\to 6\to 3\to \dots$.  Wowju is pointing out that every number in the orbit after the first odd number is a multiple of three with one exceptional case.  Now, for a more challenging question (*which might be open I don't know*) is if it will always enter the closed loop of $12,6,3$ for all starting $n$.

Comment: Ahh , now I see it , stating it in question form kinda distracted me. Thanks @Wojowu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get to 1 by starting there or division by 2. We can see that any power of 2 will eventually reach 1. There is no odd option, assuming we always start with positive integers, that reaches 1. Since that is the case, we must inquire whether there is an odd option reaches a power of 2.

Our equation for an odd number is n=3n+3. We can show that 3n+3 will be divisible by 3 for any value of n:

3n+3=3(n+1)

Because no power of 2 is also a multiple of 3, no odd step can ever reach a power of 2. Therefore, the only values of n that reach 1 are the powers of 2.

Comment: Editing for clarity quickly.